# Any way to get modern UI apps for windows 8.1 after the windows store shutdown?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui

So, as you can see in the title, I really wanna have modern ui apps in windows 8.1 because I'm a windows 8 fan and im still running that version on my tablet.
So for example like idk, maybe a modern ui/metro ui browser or apps generally.
is there anyway to do that?
or even like, maybe running desktop apps on the fullscreen mode?

Comment: Windows 8.x is EoL. Windows 10 will be soon. You're living in the past. Using ANY unsupported, unpatched OS online is dangerous for you and anybody else because those are easy targets for criminal activities.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 8.1 support ended on January 10, 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-8-1-support-ended-on-january-10-2023-3cfd4cde-f611-496a-8057-923fba401e93),
so that Microsoft Store no longer exists. Most of the apps inside the
current Microsoft Store require Windows 10 as a minimum.

If you wish to remain in Windows 8.1, you will need to get your apps
from other sources.

To [How to Download Microsoft Store Apps Without the Microsoft Store](https://www.makeuseof.com/download-microsoft-store-apps-without-microsoft-store/),
you may try to use the [Adguard store](https://store.rg-adguard.net/),
but I don't know how useful it is. When working, it's supposed to
provide old versions of the Windows operating system,
Microsoft Store apps, and more.

For more sources for apps, see the article
[5 Best Microsoft Store Alternatives to Download Apps on PC](https://www.minitool.com/news/microsoft-store-alternative.html),
which describes Softonic, AppAgg, Ninite, FileHippo and Steam (for games).